# How to install over existing installation on an encrypted filesystem?

Tags: system-installation, encryption

Is there a way to configure the Ubuntu installer to re-install over an existing Ubuntu installation on an encrypted filesystem?

```
# lsblk
nvme0n1             259:0    0   1.8T  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1         259:1    0   731M  0 part  /boot
├─nvme0n1p2         259:2    0     1K  0 part  
└─nvme0n1p5         259:3    0   1.8T  0 part  
  └─nvme0n1p5_crypt 253:0    0   1.8T  0 crypt 
    ├─z--vg-root    253:1    0   1.8T  0 lvm   /
    └─z--vg-swap_1  253:2    0   976M  0 lvm   [SWAP]
```

I've seen plenty of guides on how to re-install Ubuntu over an existing installation, but none of those were encrypted.

Comment: Do you care about the data that is already there at all, or do you just want to wipe the drive and then install onto the wiped drive?

Comment: @cocomac, I'd like to keep what is there, not wipe it clean.